# Amazon S3 Server

Tags: visual-c++, amazon-s3

How Dropbox patching delta on Amazon S3, how they are applying rdiff algorithm on Amazon S3 Server, because that's third party server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For amazon S3 you may use metadata fields to store additional information. As I know there is no partial update in S3 keys

Comment: I want to use my code on Amazon to apply RDiff functionality on my files. Can I use Amazon EC2 or S3 service to run my code on Amazon so I can add delta in old files which are stored on Amazon server?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is just a storage. You can store file as you need. Probably they are using some sort of chunking. And then just update corresponding chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox likely uses something like duplicity - rsync.

Basically this gives them chunks of data (up to 4MB) in size. Each chunk is SHA hashed, so that they only have to store each different chunk once in their storage (which is on S3). Then each file is simply a list of which chunks are needed to make up the file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicity_(software)